# How to cancel facebook login?

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I have just added a *facebook* feature to my mobile game-app and implemented SSO (Single Sign-On) according to the tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/.

If the user has not installed facebook's app, SSO launches safari which displays the facebook login page. However, some users may not like to proceed (they may not even have a facebook account).

Can I somehow configure SSO to make it possible for the user to roll back and return to the game without logging in to facebook?

Comment: Doesn't the OS does this when pressing the back button?

Comment: @alfa64 No, There is no back button!

Comment: The user may close safari by pressing the physical home button, and then launch my app again. But this is not a good solution.

Comment: My bad, i thought it was like android. Can't you embed a safari broswer and a cancel button inside your app?

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution...

Answer (score 2):

An alternative: You could change the authorize method in **Facebook.m** to have an inAuthApp flag:

```
  - (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions usingInAppAuth: (BOOL) inAppAuth {
      self.permissions = permissions;
      [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth: (inAppAuth) ? NO : YES safariAuth: (inAppAuth) ? NO : YES];
  }
```

This code:

```
[facebook authorize:permissions usingInAppAuth:YES];
```

forces the authentication process to work inside a UIWebView and there the user could cancel the process without leaving the app.

Comment: Yes this may be a solution... But I wish there was some way to make  facebook display a cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the
[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/](http://UIWebView)

And a cancel button.