# Cancel Facebook login not displayed (Swift)

Tags: facebook, swift

I have included the option to login to Facebook in my game and it works fine and appears as below. But how can a user cancel if they don't want to login or create a new Facebook account but simply want to play the game Facebook-free?

[image: Facebook login]

If I tap the button above, I get a screen asking for my login or to create a new account. No option to cancel anywhere there either.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705450/how-to-cancel-facebook-login) to this question but being a newbie who started out directly with Swift, I don't know how to port that answer there.

I load my button in my GameViewController.swift file, like so

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.authenticateLocalPlayer()
        self.fbLoginView.delegate = self
        self.fbLoginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]}
```

And have the following functions in my AppDelegate.swift file

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FBLoginView.self
        FBProfilePictureView.self
        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: NSString?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        var wasHandled:Bool = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication)
        return wasHandled
    }
```

Am I supposed to tweak something in here? What?

Comment: they can't cancel, they need to logout.

Comment: How can they logout if they don't have a Facebook account?

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me [Swift Facebook Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371672/swift-facebook-login?rq=1)

I added this part of the code mentioned there into my GameViewController.swift file

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
// Whenever a person opens the app, check for a cached session
    if FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.CreatedTokenLoaded {
        // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
        FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], allowLoginUI: false, completionHandler: {
            (session, state, error) -> Void in
            self.sessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
        })
    }
    return true
}

func sessionStateChanged(session : FBSession, state : FBSessionState, error : NSError?) {
// If the session was opened successfully
    if  state == FBSessionState.Open {
    println("Session Opened")
    }
// If the session closed
    if state == FBSessionState.Closed {
    println("Closed")
    }
}
```

This code displayed the Facebook login view with the cancel button showing, unlike my earlier button.

I then edited my handleError delegate function like so

```
func loginView(loginView : FBLoginView!, handleError:NSError) {
    println("Error: \(handleError.localizedDescription)")
    loginView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

So now when the user taps the cancel key the entire Facebook login thing goes away.